# Como saber quais linhas não estão em determinados grupos?

Tags: sql

Eu gostaria de saber quais ids não estão presentes em determinados grupos por determinado período de tempo. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT id from table1
```

Resulta na seguinte saida:

```
id 
1
2
3
4
5
```

E a consulta :

```
select Id, DateStart,DateFinish from table2 
group by DateStart,DateFinish, Id
order by Id, DateStart
```

Resulta em :

```
Id DateStart DateFinish
1   2017        2019
2   2017        2019
3   2017        2019 
2   2014        2016
4   2014        2016
```

A saída que quero saber é quais ids da tabela1 não estão nos respectivos agrupamentos da tabela2?

A saída desejada seria algo do tipo:

```
id DateStart DateFinish
4   2017        2019
5   2017        2019 
1   2014        2016
3   2014        2016
5   2014        2016
```

Comment: Amigo, seu exemplo ficou um pouco confuso, respondi baseado no que consegui interpretar, caso tenha deixado passar algo por favor me avise nos comentários para que possa adequar minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver este problema, podemos utilizar a cláusula EXISTS, que de acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Especifica uma subconsulta a ser testada quanto à existência de
> linhas.

Então, para o exemplo que você deu, a query ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
select * from table2 t2
WHERE t2.id=t1.id AND t2.DateStart=t1.DateStart AND t2.DateFinish=t1.DateFinish
);
```

Dessa forma, ele selecionará os valores da tabela 1 que não estejam presentes na tabela 2. Você pode ver funcionando e testar [aqui no SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/731174/7/0).
Recomendo ler este artigo do iMasters: [Entendendo as cláusulas Exists e Not Exists](https://imasters.com.br/banco-de-dados/entendendo-as-clausulas-exists-e-not-exists).

Comment: Infelizmente o meu problema é como está no exemplo. Na tabela 1 eu só tenho os ids e na tabela 2 eu tenho os ids e as datas. Não tenho como comparar as datas para saber se tem ou não o id lá.  Tenho que de alguma forma agrupar pelas datas e verificar para cada grupo se o id da tabela 1 não existe em cada grupo da tabela 2.

Comment: Mas o ID que está na tabela 2 é o ID dos registros da tabela 1?(Chave-estrangeira)

Comment: Sim, os ids da segunda tabela são chave estrangeira dos da primeira tabela.

Comment: Remover a verificação das datas dentro do select deve resolver então, pelo que entendi.

Comment: Mas ai vai me dar quais ids da tabela 1 não existem na tabela 2. Mas eu quero sabe quais ids da tabela 1 não existem em cada grupo da tabela 2. É como se a tabela 1 fosse ids dos produtos e a tabela 2 fosse os produtos vendidos por anos, então nesse caso eu estaria querendo saber quais produtos deixaram de ser vendidos em cada ano e não quais produtos nunca foram vendidos.